# Wordpress - Custom Post - Custom Fields

Tags: wordpress

I've installed a plugin for Wordpress Titled "CMS Press" onto my Site.

I have created two custom fields within a custom post I've called "The Team"

The code for the page is as follows :

```
<div class="span16"> <!-- This is column 1 -->

            <?php if ( have_posts() ) while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

            <div class="pagehead"><h2 class="title_page"><?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'title_page', true);?></h2></div>

            <div class="span6 subcontent">
                <?php 
                        $args = array ('post_type' => 'team');
                        $lastposts = get_posts( $args );
                            foreach($lastposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>
                                <div class="teamsubhead">
                                    <h2 class="team_page"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                                    <h3 class="job_title"><?php get_post_meta($post->ID, 'jobtitle', true); ?></h3>
                                </div>
                            <?php the_content(); ?>
                <?php endforeach; ?>                    
            </div>

           <?php endwhile; ?>
     </div>
```

The custom field I created in my custom post is called "jobtitle" I am trying to retrieve that from this line of code

> ```
> <h3 class="job_title"><?php get_post_meta($post->ID, 'jobtitle', true); ?></h3>
> ```

However nothing is getting output at all.

Can someone help me with this. I suspect it may be something to do with the loop and my new query being in a new loop?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try it with `echo` at the beginning:

`<?php echo get_post_meta($post->ID, 'jobtitle', true); ?>`

Comment: Urgh! That hurts knowing how simple that could have been. Many Thanks